# AngularJs Check if user role matchs state role for authentication

Tags: angularjs

I'm building an authentication system and I've done almost everything. I'm stuck in the authorization based on user role. If I use numbers, like user.role > 1, pass, if not, return false, I can make it work properly.

But I'm planning to move to an array based role, so I can create 'modules' and make a better control.

#### Auth process

It all starts with a return from the database, if the user/pass is ok, the DB will return a json array containing user name, id and roles, like this:

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John Doe',
    role: ['user', 'order', 'service']
}
```

In my $state, i have it defined like this:

```
.state('home', {
    [...code...]
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        role: ['user']
    }
})
.state('sales', {
    [...code...]
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        role: ['sales', 'admin']
    }
})
.state('order', {
    [...code...]
    data: {
        requireLogin: true,
        role: ['order', 'admin']
    }
})
```

So for example, that user should be able to access the state 'order' and 'home', because at least one of the roles is in the .state data role. But I'm having trouble validating it inside my factory. I kind of made it, but sometimes it returns some other unxpected numbers, or at least i don't know the proper validation.

This is my factory:

```
//token = user data returned from data base;
//type = user role from state;
var _getTipo = function(token, type) {
    var authUser = token.indexOf(type);
    return authUser;
};
```

Sometimes i get the return -1, 10 or 2..

What i did wrong? Or whats the proper way to check if at least one of the user roles is in the state role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever I do user authentication I use a directive as an attribute like this:

```
app.directive('permissions', function (currentUser) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            priority: 100000,
            scope: false,
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {
                var accessDenied = true;

                var attribute = attr.permissions;
                if (currentUser.role.indexOf(attribute) !== -1) {
                    accessDenied = false;
                }

                if (accessDenied) {
                    element.children().remove();
                    element.remove();
                }

            }
        };
    });
```

You would then call it like this:

```
<div permissions="user">
   //info
</div>
```

You would just need to pass the currentUser object to the directive. Or you could just change your factory:

```
var _getTipo = function(token, type) {
    var authenticated = false
    for(var i = 0;i < token.role.length;i++){
        var userRole = token.role[i];
        for(var x = 0;x < type.length;x++){
            var stateRole = type[x];
            if (userRole == stateRole) {
                authenticated = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return authenticated;
};
```

To turn this string: "['user', 'sales']" into an array:

JAVASCRIPT

```
var string = "['user', 'sales']";
var array = string.replace('"[',"").replace(']"',"").split("', '");
```

PHP

```
$string = "['user', 'sales']";
$string = str_replace('"[',"",$string);
$string = str_replace(']"',"",$string);
$array = explode("', '",$string);
```

Comment: The problem is, I already have everything working, but instead of a string role, I'm using a number. So I don't plan to change what I already have, since i just need to check wheter or not that string is in the state role (if at least one of them match at least one of the user role).

Comment: I edited my answer to just modify your factory and that should work if you are passing exactly what the comments above the factory specify.

Comment: Ok, there is only one thing wrong with your code, the second `for` should use a different `var i`, It was with an infinite loop, i changed to var d, and it fixed. But I'm with some woerd behavior, I think it's my array with syntax errors, I'll check with the return and will get back to you in a bit. But thanks, I think that will do!

Comment: Ah, good call. Didn't even catch that. But, glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: Sure! I just need to fix my php return (which isn't my area), it's returning a string "['user', 'sales']" instead of a proper array. So the `for` is repeat just this caracter `[`

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a way to turn that string into an array. I included javascript and php syntax.

Comment: I'll check it tomorrow. It's late here. But I'll get back to you, for sure! Thanks for now

Comment: The problem is with my array now. I'll have to check with the guys from the php. But I used a hand-made array of roles and it worked. Thanks for your time and support, Jon.